# Explain this nested for loop?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nested-loops

This is creating a square with the width and height already set up and printing it out into the output using dashes, And it runs perfectly; But I don't seem to full understand what the second and third loop are doing and hows its running.

```
- (void)draw {
    for (int w = 1; w <= width; w++) {
        printf("-");
    }

    ***
    for (int h = 0; h <= height; h++) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("|");

        for (int space = 0; space <= width; space++) {
            printf(" ");

        }

        printf("|");
    }
    ***

    for (int w = 1; w <= width; w++) {
        if (w == 1) {
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("-");

        if (w == width)
            printf("\n");
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middle loop you are asking about basically draws the left and right side of the box, one '|' at a time, from top-to-bottom... It prints the first | on the left side, then a bunch of spaces, then the first | on the right side. It then moves down to the next line and repeats all over again.

It's probably easier to visualize it:

After the first loop you're left with something like this (assuming width = 15)

```
 ---------------
```

Once the second starts, it inserts a newline and prints a pipe `|` on the left, leaving you with:

`---------------
|`

Then the inner loop inserts spaces for the amount your width is, (represented here as `o`) leaving you with this:

```
 ---------------
|ooooooooooooooo
```

After the spaces have been inserted, another pipe is drawn on the right side, and you're left with:

```
 ---------------
|               |
```

This continues `height` times until you're left with (assuming height = 5):

```
 ---------------
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
```

Finally, the last loop prints the bottom, just like the top:

```
 ---------------
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
 ---------------
```

Comment: Thank you, really liked the broken down explanation.

Answer (score 1):

"\n" means new line so the **second** loop starts a new line then prints a pipe (vertical bar).

```
for (int h = 0; h <= height; h++) {  
    printf("\n");
    printf("|");
```

The **third** loop prints a bunch of spaces.

```
for (int space = 0; space <= width; space++) {  
    printf(" ");
```

The **second** loop then print another pipe for the right edge of the box.

```
printf("|");
```

The **second** loop then "loops" and does this all over again a bunch of times.

The last loop prints a new line then a bunch of dashes "-" for the bottom edge.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop prints out the top horizontal dashed line.

The next loop prints the two vertical dashed lines for each row, first printing the left line dash, then looping over the width and printing spaces then printing the right line dash. This happens for each row of the height of the square.

Finally the last loop prints the bottom line's dashs.